# Need help to put 2 div side by side (I can't make inline-block nor float work)

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling to add a youtube livestream next to a twitch chat. They don't get on the same line. I have tried using `float` and `display: inline-block` but I can't make them work for some reason. Some help would be very appreciated.

```css
#stream {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#chat {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="stream" align="left">
  <iframe height="935" width="80%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6TSxUwq_D0s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="chat" align="right" align="top">
  <iframe src="http://twitch.tv/riotgames/chat?popout=" height="935" width="375"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: The selector for a class in CSS is a dot and not a hash.

Comment: `height` and `width` are already provided for both `iframe` and it is acting accordingly. Also, `#` is used instead of `.`

Comment: Just change `#stream` and `#chat` into `.stream` and `.chat`. OR in the html change `class=` into `id=`

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few errors:

- you are using ID selectors in CSS (`#`) and using class(`.`) in HTML, you have to match them.
- if you are going to `float` the `div`s then no need to use `inline-block`
- using deprecated HTML attributes such as `align="left"`
- avoid using `width/height` in HTML `iframe`, instead use CSS

```css
.stream,
.chat {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="stream">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6TSxUwq_D0s"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="chat">
  <iframe src="http://twitch.tv/riotgames/chat?popout="></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, about the width/height in html i know it's not ideal but I dont know how to address css to the iframe inside the div

Comment: @Ren3994 just use something like `.stream iframe { width:xxx px; height: xxx px}`

Comment: @Ren3994 if this solve your issue make sure you mark this answer as accepted for future readers know too.

Comment: I tried it but didn't think about the "px"... Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need this :

**CSS**

```
.stream, .chat {
  float: left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="stream">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6TSxUwq_D0s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="chat">
  <iframe src="http://twitch.tv/riotgames/chat?popout=" ></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: why 49% and why define width at all?

Comment: @Chris - Happy pappi?